# Laravel Reset Password Reminder , passing variables to Blade template

Tags: php, laravel-4

Hi I have the following code in my PasswordController.php but its not working?

```
      // get the user info..
      $user = DB::table('users')
      ->where('email', '=' , Input::get('email'))
      ->first();

      if (empty($user))
       return Redirect::back()->with('message', "email doesn't exsist!");

      // set email template
      Config::set('auth.reminder.email', 'emails.auth.admin-reminder');

      $response = Password::remind($credentials, function($message) use ($user){

              $message->with('name'=> $user->first_name);
      $message->subject(trans('assword Reset')); 
                          });
```

I am trying to pass $user->first_name to my blade email template? How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: I think I figured it out

Comment: If you found the answer please [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that others can benefit from it as well.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out ,

Before 
      Password::remind

we add this :

```
    View::composer('emails.auth.admin-reminder', function($view) use ($user) {
          $view->with(['name'  => $user->first_name]);
       });
```

You can pass to the view as many variables as you want